# How can I find a big uploaded zip file in the Media library?

Tags: uploads, ziparchive

I need to upload big files 500 MG and more to my wordpress site so that these can be used as downloadable products on woocommerce plugin. I managed to connect my site to Fillzilla found the folder where other zipfiles used for the same reason were located in my Public html and successfully uploaded the file.

However when I went in my media library the file was not there.

Is there a way to make this uploaded Zip file in my Media library?
I tried to copy the file's ulr to woocommerce but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The Media Library only lists files that were uploaded within the WordPress admin. There are plugins that will find uploaded files and add them to the Media Library.

Found this plugin pretty quickly:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/media-sync/